# Non-zero homomorphism of unital algebras maps unit to unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

Suppose that $R, S$ are unital algebras, and
$$\varphi: R \longrightarrow S$$
Homomorphism of algebras.Here is the proof that surjective homomorphism of algebras maps unit to unit. (Moreover it's true for an unital rings, isn't it?)
$$\varphi(a) = \varphi (a \times 1) = \varphi (a) \varphi (1) =\varphi (1 \times a) = \varphi (1)\varphi (a) \implies \varphi (1) = 1 $$
It seems to me, that here nowhere i used surjectivity,but it's obvious that for not surjective homomorphism it's nor true, bacause we can just take a zero homomorphism.Where is a mistake?I suppose that $\varphi(1)$ will be a unit only in $\varphi (R)$ which is a subalgebra of $S$, but not in whole $S$?

Comment: You want to show that $\phi(1)s=s\phi(1)=s$ for all $s\in S$; you pick $a$ such that $\phi(a)=s$. Alternatively, you are showing that $\phi(1)$ is a unit of the image, therefore...

Comment: Consider $\mathbb Z \longrightarrow \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ via $n \mapsto (n, 0)$. This is not onto and not unital. Try running your proof on this map to see why it doesn't work.

Comment: More generally, if $(M,\bullet,e_M)$ and $(N,*,e_N)$ are two [monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid), and $f : M \to N$ is a surjective map with the property that $f(m \bullet m') = f(m)*f(m')$ for any $m,m' \in M$, *then* $f(e_M) = e_N$; that is, $f$ is necessarily a monoid homomorphism.